# How can you use iOS UIAutomation to see if the application badge is correct?

Tags: ios-ui-automation

Like many apps, we badge the application to indicate $SOMETHING.  How can we use UIAutomation to check that the badge is correct?  The problem, of course, is that UIAutomation gives you lots of ways to interact with your application, but the badge is outside the app.  (Note that I'm not talking about badges on tab bars; I'm talking about badges on the application icon.)

Comment: Apple does not gives a straight forward way to check anything outside of the app you are using with uiautomation. What do you mean by "checking the badge". Would it be enough for you just to suspend the app for a while so you will be able to visually validate the badge number? Or you are looking for it to be automated process?

Comment: We're definitely looking for an automated process.